# How can the Cassandra commitlog be corrupted?

Tags: cassandra

This is the second time my commitlog is corrupted, and the server refuses to start. What worries me is that I get these error issues even if no update were made to the database.

My config says that commitlog are synced every 10s seconds, so how can a file be corrupt unless a crash occurs within these 10 seconds?

Is this a Cassandra bug? Or by design, i.e. bad design?

I am using 3.4 on Windows 10, Datastax installer.

In the stdout log, the last part is

```
INFO  06:17:39 Replaying C:\Program Files\DataStax-DDC\data\commitlog\CommitLog-6-1471353812251.log, C:\Program Files\DataStax-DDC\data\commitlog\CommitLog-6-1471353812252.log, C:\Program Files\DataStax-DDC\data\commitlog\CommitLog-6-1471411951134.log, C:\Program Files\DataStax-DDC\data\commitlog\CommitLog-6-1471454506802.log, C:\Program Files\DataStax-DDC\data\commitlog\CommitLog-6-1471532812678.log
ERROR 06:17:39 Exiting due to error while processing commit log during initialization.
org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer$CommitLogReplayException: Could not read commit log descriptor in file C:\Program Files\DataStax-DDC\data\commitlog\CommitLog-6-1471353812252.log
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer.handleReplayError(CommitLogReplayer.java:611) [apache-cassandra-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer.recover(CommitLogReplayer.java:373) [apache-cassandra-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer.recover(CommitLogReplayer.java:236) [apache-cassandra-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.recover(CommitLog.java:192) [apache-cassandra-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.recover(CommitLog.java:172) [apache-cassandra-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:283) [apache-cassandra-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:551) [apache-cassandra-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:680) [apache-cassandra-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
```

Comment: Hi, were you able to debug this issue. we are facing the same error . I know its an old question. But were you able to fix it ?

Comment: No, and I didn't get any answer in cassandra jira. I think they want me to use a plain cassandra version, not datastax. My plan is to do that when I come nearer deploy.

Comment: Most likely, it is the same problem as this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11995, which is fixed in Cassandra 3.11

Answer (score 1):

I have seen similar errors. This happens, when Cassandra process gets crahed may be due to OOM. Run "dmesg" and check if it was killed due to OOM.  In that case there is possibility that commit log it was writing to was corrupted or its of 0kb file (check size of above file in error), and it throws the above error when Cassandra is restarted and it replays that file.

Comment: i have 0kb commit log and i am not able to delete it. how can i solve this issue

Comment: As I mentioned, this happens when your Cassandra has got killed by OS OOM killer. Run "dmesg" and check if it was killed due to OOM. To solve it for longtime, you should make sure to tune heap memory settings. It's an indication your process is OOM. Sometime, deleting and restarting these files will help, but not always as it recreates these 0kb files again